# Finding the minimum number of entries that will give me a confidence in the result

Tags: estimation, sample-size

I have a big number of hotels, and each hotel has an number of price matches. There are two types of price matches : exact price match and price mismatch.

The number of price matches per hotel could vary between 1 and 15000, and this distribution has a skewness coefficient of 2.02 .

For each hotel I want to compute the exact price match ratio. The formula is number of exact price matches divided by all price matches.

But I only want to do that for the hotels what have a decent number of price matches. I mean, if a hotel has only one price match and it's a exact price match, I can't be confident that the actual score (100% exact price match ration) is relevant.

How can I find the minimum number of price matches for one hotel, such that the result can be considered statistically relevant (the result can be trusted)?